# Tailwind text align bottom

Tags: html, css, vue.js, tailwind-css

I have the following code that creates two <p> tags to store some text:

```
<p v-if="my_property <= 0" class="text-green-500 text-lg font-bold">{{Math.abs(my_value)}}%</p>
<p v-else class="text-red-500 text-lg font-bold">{{my_value}}%</p>
<div class="inline-block align-bottom bg-yellow-500 align-text-bottom">
   <p class="text-gray-500 text-sm ml-1 inline-block align-text-bottom align-bottom">tsa</p>
</div>
```

I'm trying to have the last <p> tag align bottom as compared to the first. I've tried putting the <p> tag currently in the <div> inside and outside a <div> tag, but I can't seem to get the result right, and it currently looks like this:

[image]

I want the "tsa" text to appear here:

[image]

What do I need to change about the way I've currently got it?

**Note**: I've highlighted the <div> in yellow to just show the text is not aligned to the bottom of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can solve your issue by adding a flex-container for all your `<p>` tags.

```
  <div class="flex items-baseline">
    <p v-if="my_property <= 0" class="text-green-500 text-lg font-bold">{{Math.abs(my_value)}}%</p>
    <p v-else class="text-red-500 text-lg font-bold">29%</p>
    <p class="text-gray-500 text-sm ml-1">tsa</p>
  </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the below code for the solution

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>


<div v-if="my_property <= 0" class="text-green-500 text-lg font-bold">{{Math.abs(my_value)}}% 
  <span class="text-gray-500 text-sm ml-1 inline-block align-text-bottom align-bottom">tsa</span>
</div>

<div v-else class="text-red-500 text-lg font-bold">{{my_value}}% 
  <span class="text-gray-500 text-sm ml-1 inline-block align-text-bottom align-bottom">tsa</span>
</div>
```

Comment: 'align-text-bottom' applies the same CSS properties as 'align-bottom'.